# Differenza tra "ci si vede" e "ci si rivede"

Tags: word-usage, idioms, difference

Qual è la differenza? Ho sentito tutti e due come saluti e non ci riesco a trovare la differenza.

Comment: Benvenuto su ItalianSE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La differenza è minima, sono perfettamente intercambiabili, semplicemente "ci si rivede" vuol dire "ci si vede di nuovo/un'altra volta", ma possono essere usati nello stesso contesto